# No of matrices of rank 3

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

I was tackling this problem 
How many 4 x 3 matrices can be formed of rank 3 where entries are coming from a field  of 3 elements.
When I solved it as finding total no of linearly independent sets with cardinality 4 in F^4(F). Assuming that each column of the matrix is coming from F^4(F).
I am getting correct answer as follows 
(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)
 But if I am solving this problem as taking each row from F^3 (F). 
Then our task is to find matrices with rank 3. So any ordered basis can serve to form any three rows of A and remaining row can be anything 
So I am getting (3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)3^3.
But it doesn't matches with that answer which I got using columns. Where I am doing mistake I am unable to identify.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only counting matrices where the upper $3\times3$ part has full rank. You need to add three more cases: If dependence first occurs in the third row, we have $(3^3-1)(3^3-3)3^2(3^3-3^2)$ options; if it first occurs in the second row, we have $(3^3-1)3(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)$ options, and if it first occurs in the first row, we have $1(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)$ options, for a total of

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)3^3+(3^3-1)(3^3-3)3^2(3^3-3^2)+(3^3-1)3(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)+1(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)
\\
&=&
(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)(3^3+3^2+3+1)
\\
&=&
(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)\frac{3^4-1}{3-1}
\\
&=&
(3^3-1)(3^3-3)\frac{3^3-3^2}{3-1}(3^4-1)
\\
&=&
(3^3-1)(3^3-3)3^2(3^4-1)
\\
&=&
(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)(3^4-1)
\\
&=&
(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

One more piece of advice: You would probably have found the error yourself if you'd tried the simpler case of a $2\times1$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much.  U have explained nicely. And thanks for your valuable advice. I was knowing that I am missing something silly but it was not at all coming to me.  In addition may I ask you that how can I be good in linear algebra?  I know the terms but to be able to think more intuitively what I should do? I will be grateful to get any help

Comment: @prakashnainwal: That's a difficult question, and the answer depends on what comes natural to you. I often find it helpful to think geometrically, in terms of lines and planes, but people are different that way. Anyway, as with most things, the main thing is experience, figuring lots of things out for yourself :-)

Comment: Yaa that's true. For me also geometry helps me many time to figure out the answer. I want to know what would be good approach to go through different books or to just stick to one book. What your experience says ? I have gone through few books like Hoffman Kunje, Sheldon Axler etc and I found these books gave me an insight to think better than earlier. But as I have not solved them fully it gave me the feeling that is this the reason that I am feeling like gap in my knowledge.what may be a good way to study mathematics in your words?

Comment: @prakashnainwal: I don't think I've ever gone through an entire math book. Very little of what I know is from books. I took some math courses at university, and mostly I just figured things out when I needed them e.g. while I was doing software development; and quite a large part of what I know I learned by answering questions here and searching for the tools I needed, here and on Wikipedia and on the web in general. But how people learn is very individual, books might be the right way for you, it's really hard to give advice just based on a chat.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your own experience with me. Thank you sir.